# Difference in oracle 11.2.0.1.0 and oracle 11.2.0.2.0 while inserting a value into the table using sequence

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

### In Oracle 11.2.0.1.0:

1) I created a table.

`create table m1(id number(5,2), version number(5,2), primary key (id));`

2) I created a sequence.

`CREATE SEQUENCE m1_id_sq;`

3) I inserted values into the table.

`insert into m1(id, version) values (m1_id_sq.nextval, 1);`

4) output.

`id`  `version`

`-------------`

`2`         `1`

*I understand the reason for id=2 is due to deferred_segment_creation feature introduced from 11.2.0.1.0 onwards.

*I created an user instance in oracle and I ran the above three commands. Not as a master.

Now I follow the same steps

### in Oracle 11.2.0.2.0,

but the output I got is,

`id`  `version`

`-------------`

`1`         `1`

Please explain why the id=1 in oracle 11.2.0.2.0 whereas id=2 in oracle 11.2.0.1.0. Great thanks!

Comment: `I understand the reason for id=2 is due to deferred_segment_creation` why do you think so?

Comment: What's your exact `SELECT` query?

Comment: @Alvaro.G.Vicario: simple select query,
`Select * from m1;`

Comment: @beherenow: But, May I know, why oracle 11.2.0.2.0 is behaving differently from 11.2.0.1.0?

Comment: @beherenow: Deferred segment creation, If set to true, then segments for tables and their dependent objects (LOBs, indexes) will not be created until the first row is inserted into the table.

So, when i use `insert` for the first time and if that `insert` statement uses `sequence` to populate the table, then the value of the `sequence` will be 2. 

Reason: sequence value will be 1 when the table gets created and incremented to 2 when the table gets populated.


This is according to my understanding. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The table and sequence are not related - there is no dependency, unless indirectly through a trigger, which you don't have here. Ansd sequences don't have segments. You ran the three statements back-to-back as shown, with nothing in between - you didn't do `insert`, `rollback`, `insert` in 11.2.0.1 case, for example?

Comment: @AlexPoole: Yes, I ran my three statements one by one. I didn't do any insert-rollback-insert.

Comment: I expect that the change is the result of a deliberate error fix in the Oracle code.

Comment: Note 1050193.1 does indeed say this is expected with deferred segment creation. That doesn't suggest the behaviour is changed in later versions, but I don't see it starting with 2 in 11.2.0.3 with `deferred_segment_creation=TRUE` so it seems to be been 'fixed'. This shouldn't really matter anyway - you'll get gaps in sequences for other reasons so you shouldn't rely on it starting with 1.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: I will verify this. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @AlexPoole: Thanks a ton. Can you give me a link for the Note 1050193.1?

Comment: @Murali - you need an Oracle support account to see it; if you have one then log in to support.oracle.com and then search for that number.  I think David is right; it seems to suggest this is expected behaviour but it's clearly changed and the note refers to an unpublished bug - if they have fixed that then it doesn't seem to be acknowledged anywhere so I don't think you'll get a definitive answer.

Comment: There are 2 good blog entries at orawin.info site about this situation: [Post1](https://web.archive.org/web/20151004175547/http://orawin.info/blog/2011/11/17/new-defaults-old-side-effects/) , [Post2](https://web.archive.org/web/20150914162717/http://orawin.info/blog/2010/04/25/new-features-new-defaults-new-side-effects/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem may have to due with the fact that NOORDER is the default with Oracle Sequences, especially if you're running a RAC environment.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm

I've learned that with Sequences, if I want to guarantee that they be sequential I usually have to add the following keywords when creating the sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE m1_id_sq ORDER NOCACHE;
```

Edit to refer to above comments:

As noted by Alex Poole in the comments above:

> "This shouldn't really matter anyway - you'll get gaps in sequences
> for other reasons so you shouldn't rely on it starting with 1"

The NOORDER being the default for sequences explains this issue.

Alex Poole also noted a known issue: Oracle Note 1050193.1 (requires an Oracle Support account) related to an issue with `deferred_segment_creation=TRUE`.

ThinkJet also refers to the following articles that show that early versions of Oracle had some issues with sequences and deferred segments:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150914162717/http://orawin.info/blog/2010/04/25/new-features-new-defaults-new-side-effects/

https://web.archive.org/web/20151004175547/http://orawin.info/blog/2011/11/17/new-defaults-old-side-effects/

Comment: All the reasons with answers are already posted in comments. see Alex Poole comment

Comment: I did see the comments, but it's worth noting the issue with RAC environments and the NOORDER parameter being the default for sequences. I can't add comments to the default post yet, otherwise I would have done so there.